# Disable <a> tag of <ul> but not of its associated <li>

Tags: jquery, navigation

My navigation menu looks like this which is generated by wordpress wp_nav_menus function.

```
<ul id="main">
    <li class="item1"><a href="some links"></a></li>
    <li class="item2"><a href="some links"></a></li>
    <li class="item3 menu-item-has-children" ><a href="some links">Letters</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="item4" ><a href="some links">A</a></li>
            <li class="item5" ><a href="some links">B</a></li>
            <li class="item6" ><a href="some links">C</a></li>
            <li class="item7 menu-item-has-children" ><a href="some links">Numbers</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li class="item4" ><a href="some links">1</a></li>
                    <li class="item5" ><a href="some links">2</a></li>
                    <li class="item6" ><a href="some links">3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to disable the main link that has submenu . In above example "Letters" and "Numbers" and not their associated `'<li>'` tags links.
i tried this.

```
  $('.menu-item-has-children').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

But it disables all other sub menu too..

Comment: `if ( e.target === this ) e.preventDefault();`

Comment: `$('.menu-item-has-children > a').click(...)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this...

```
  $('.menu-item-has-children > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```